# How to use multiple GPUs in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I use this command to use a GPU.

```python
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

But, I want to use two GPUs in **jupyter**, like this:

```python
device = torch.device("cuda:0,1" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

Answer (score 92):

Assuming that you want to distribute the data across the available GPUs (If you have batch size of 16, and 2 GPUs, you might be looking providing the 8 samples to each of the GPUs), and not really spread out the parts of models across difference GPU's. This can be done as follows:

**If you want to use all the available GPUs:**

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

model = CreateModel()

model= nn.DataParallel(model)
model.to(device)
```

**If you want to use specific GPUs:**
(For example, using 2 out of 4 GPUs)

```
device = torch.device("cuda:1,3" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu") ## specify the GPU id's, GPU id's start from 0.

model = CreateModel()

model= nn.DataParallel(model,device_ids = [1, 3])
model.to(device)
```

**To use the specific GPU's by setting OS environment variable:**

Before executing the program, set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` variable as follows:

`export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1,3`  (Assuming you want to select 2nd and 4th GPU)

Then, within program, you can just use `DataParallel()` as though you want to use all the GPUs. (similar to 1st case). Here the GPUs available for the program is restricted by the OS environment variable.

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

model = CreateModel()

model= nn.DataParallel(model)
model.to(device)
```

In all of these cases, the **data has to be mapped to the device**.

If `X` and `y` are the data:

```
X.to(device)
y.to(device)
```

Comment: How do you get access to a network of gpu's or cpu's. Lets say i have 2 phones and i want to use the gpu's in the phones to train my model. Any idea where i should start to be able to do this?

Comment: Sorry Kay, I am not aware of this particular scenario.

Comment: `torch.device("cuda:0,3")` returns `device(type='cuda', index=0)` in Torch 1.3.1. Is there a point to run this line of code, if you specify ids in `nn.DataParallel(model,device_ids = [1, 3])` ?

Comment: device = torch.device("cuda:1,3" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu") ## specify the GPU id's, GPU id's start from 0. `Gives string error`

Comment: @MAC Check my answer below for the workaround

Comment: "It is recommended to use DistributedDataParallel, instead of this class, to do multi-GPU training, even if there is only a single node. See: Use nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel instead of multiprocessing or nn.DataParallel and Distributed Data Parallel." when I read https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.DataParallel.html#torch.nn.DataParallel

Comment: How do you load the separate batches on two different GPUs? Suppose my original batch size is 8. Does it get split into 4 and 4 for the two GPUs, by default, or should I specify the split? If latter is the case, how should I implement it?

Comment: It splits the batches equally on two GPUs

Answer (score 30):

Using multi-GPUs is as simply as wrapping a model in [`DataParallel`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#dataparallel-layers-multi-gpu-distributed) and increasing the batch size. Check these two tutorials for a quick start:

- [Multi-GPU Examples](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/parallelism_tutorial.html)
- [Data Parallelism](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html)

Comment: I have know something from the websites.

Maybe there isn't a simpler way to use multiple GPUs for me.

I would try again.

Thanks.

Comment: @MLXu What are you talking about? It is just adding 1-2 lines of code to original code!

Comment: Maybe I should install parallel CUDA version. Unitl now I did not try to use multiple GPUs at the same time. Because every time I tried to use multiple GPUs, nothing happened and my programs cracked after several hours. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to use some helper libraries for PyTorch:

## PyTorch Ignite library Distributed GPU training

In [there](https://pytorch.org/ignite/distributed.html) there is a concept of *context manager* for distributed configuration on:

- nccl  - torch native distributed configuration on multiple GPUs
- xla-tpu - TPUs distributed configuration

## PyTorch Lightning Multi-GPU training

[This](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/multi_gpu.html) is of possible the best option IMHO to train on CPU/GPU/TPU without changing your original PyTorch code.

Worth cheking [Catalyst](https://github.com/catalyst-team/catalyst) for similar distributed GPU options.

Comment: PyTorch LIghtning or Catalyst which is the best? And which one is easy to use?

Comment: Instead of telling you what I already stated in the answer, check this https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/lightning-vs-ignite/84972

Answer (score 3):

In 2022, PyTorch says:

> It is recommended to use DistributedDataParallel, instead of this class, to do multi-GPU training, even if there is only a single node. See: Use nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel instead of multiprocessing or nn.DataParallel and Distributed Data Parallel.

in https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.DataParallel.html#torch.nn.DataParallel

Thus, seems that we should use `DistributedDataParallel`, not `DataParallel`.

Comment: DistributedDataParallel is very hard to implement

Answer (score 2):

When I ran `naiveinception_googlenet`, the above methods didn't work for me. The following method solved my problem.

```py
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,3"  # specify which GPU(s) to be used
```

Comment: But how do I know which GPU ids are correct for my system? Could you please help?

Comment: I am not sure that I really understand your question. Usually you can find the available GPUs using "nvidia-smi", then you can the specifiy the GPU(s) to be used in the scripts.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run your code only on specific GPUs (e.g. only on GPU id 2 and 3), then you can specify that using the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2,3 variable when triggering the python code from terminal.

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2,3 python lstm_demo_example.py --epochs=30 --lr=0.001
```

and inside the code, leave it as:

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = LSTMModel()
model = nn.DataParallel(model)
model = model.to(device)
```

Source : https://glassboxmedicine.com/2020/03/04/multi-gpu-training-in-pytorch-data-and-model-parallelism/