# Increase speed Huggingface tokenizer ouput

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I need to get the last layer of embeddings from a BERT model using HuggingFace. The following code works, however is **extremely slow**, how can I **increase the speed**?

This is a toy example, my real data is made of thousands of examples with long texts.

```
import transformers
import pandas as pd
from transformers import BertModel, BertTokenizer

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased") 
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

def getPrediction(text): 
  encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')
  outputs = model(**encoded_input)
  embedding = outputs[0][:, -1]  
  embedding_1ist = embedding.cpu().detach().tolist()[0]
  return embedding_1ist

df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['First text', 'Second text']})
results =  pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x: getPrediction(x.text), axis=1))
```

Comment: It is not the tokenizer, the model is slow. BERT is a big model. You can use a GPU to speed up computation.

You can speed up the tokenization by passing `use_fast=True` to the `from_pretrained` call of the tokenizer. This will load the rust-based tokenizers, which are much faster. But I think the problem is not tokenization.

Comment: @amdex is it possible you show me a minimal example of how to implement this particular example using a GPU.

Comment: @Alfredo_MF, do you have GPU device? If so, you can refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216920/how-to-use-multiple-gpus-in-pytorch/64825728#64825728

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa I have a GPU. I will follow the link that you provided.