# How to use both gpus in kaggle for training in pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, gpu, kaggle

I was training a model in kaggle gpu.
But as I can see only one GPU is working.
[image]
I use the ordinary method for training like

```py
device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')
model = model.to(device)
```

How can I use both the gpus?

Comment: If you know that the number GPUs is exactly two, then you could set the device ids to `[cuda:0, cuda:1]`. Your question might be a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216920/how-to-use-multiple-gpus-in-pytorch. Ashwin Geet D'Sa's answer seems correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using multiple GPUs is specific to machine learning libraries. I stumbled upon the same problem while doing image segmentation in Pytorch. The solution is to use the module [torch.nn.DataParallel()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.DataParallel.html) with the model. The given code can be changed as follows:

```
device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids = [0,1]).to(device)
```

here, the `device_ids` is the index of GPUs. Suppose if you have 4 GPUs then it would be `device_ids = [0,1,2,3]` or whatever the index it maybe.

And the result of
[using both GPUs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc8GW.png) is here!.

PS: This is my first post in the prestigious stack overflow, please do share your comments and views.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the answer from Sayan Banerjee, please also remember to change the saving code: from

```
model.save_pretrained(savedModelPath)
```

to

```
model.module.save_pretrained(savedModelPath)
```

or you may lose your trained model :(

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).