How to set num_workers=4 in SLURM (PyTorch)? Which parameter should be set to 4?
I am trying to run a job on SLURM and I want to use num_workers=4 (PyTorch DataLoader) to accelerate my Neural Network training. Using 4 GPUs (with --gres=gpu:4) with nn.DataParallelModel (following https://stackoverflow.com/a/64825728/11092636) didn't accelerate much the time to train (11 hours with 1 A100 and 11 hours with 4 A100) so I'm assuming the problem/bottleneck is from the fetching of the data.
However, I am unsure which SLURM parameter I should set to 4 so that setting num_workers=4 is useful. The options I am considering are:

--ntasks
--cpus-per-task
--ntasks-per-node

Can someone please guide me on which of these parameters should be set to 4 to correctly configure my job with 4 workers? I'm having trouble understanding the difference of each of these options.
